# How to populate select options from DB

Tags: php, mysqli

What am I doing wrong here? When it populates the options it shows $name[0] and not the info from the DB. Though the correct number of options seem to be available.

```
<?php
//connect to database
$conn = mysqli_connect("example.com", "timemin", "Pass123", "timesheet");

//query database for items to populate
$sql = "SELECT DIS_NAME, NAME FROM INVITEM";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo '<select>';
echo '<option value="">Choose your favorite fruit</option>';
while($name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo '<option value="' . '$name[1]' . '">' . '$name[0]' . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: If you use `$name['DIS_NAME']` and `$name['NAME']` rather than `$name[0]` etc, when you come to add another column into a query you dont have to worry about the positioning.

Comment: That must be it @RiggsFolly, he indeed used `fetch associative`, so array uses named keys.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Add as an answer and you get the points :)

Comment: @DeDee You add this to your question afterall you did most of the work.

Comment: @RiggsFolly just done it :) Thank you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly For whatever reason it wanted the name???

Comment: @Elegance I explained why it wants names instead of numbers.

Comment: See [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) for the reason or @DeDee answer. Fetch assoc does not return numbered array, only named associative array.Names being the column names from the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be as follows, you quoted variables, that was the problem.

```
echo '<option value="' . $name['DIS_NAME'] . '">' . $name['NAME'] . '</option>';
```

Also as *RiggsFolly* mentioned, you used **fetch_assoc** so the array keys will be named accordingly `DIS_NAME` and `NAME`.
Credit to *RiggsFolly* for spotting this.

Comment: What is your database structure? Your query is probably incorrect

Comment: @Iowa15 according to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php its correct... is there reason to assume divergence?

Comment: `example.com` should possibly be `localhost` in the connection `mysqli_connect("localhost", "timemin", "Pass123", "timesheet");` in the connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly I changed if from the actual url for examples sake.

Comment: Hmm, try and just echo out the values in your variable: echo print_r($name);

Comment: Just do `print_r($name);` the `echo` is superfluous

Comment: @Iowa15 It does not return anything

Comment: Paste results in your queston, unless the problem is obvious of course

Comment: Your code appears to be proper. It must be database problem.

Comment: Let's see if there's an sql error. echo mysqli_error($conn) after you do the query

Comment: @Elegance See RiggsFolly's comment on your question.

Answer (score 2):

In php, there are two types of quotes: single quotes and double quotes. Single quotes will not parse variables, double quotes will.

If you do want to use quotes, you could do something like this:

`echo "<option value="."$name[1]".">$name[0]</option>";`

So here, the double quotes will tell php to parse the variable names

However, I would recommend doing this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $name[1] . '">' . $name[0] . '</option>';
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) SO post for more.

Comment: use `print_r($name);` to check your array. If there's nothing you have error in your SQL. If there is records, use array key names like `$name['firstname']`.